# Taking a screenshot of a UWP app on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, win-universal-app, windows-10-iot-core

Does anyone know how / if it's possible to take a screenshot of a UWP application running on a raspberry pi?

Answer (score 1):

If you can attach a keyboard, I'd try pressing the Win+PrintScr buttons - that saves a screenshot into the Pictures/Screenshots folder. (If you can access that in IoT core.)

Otherwise you can just use the RenderTargetBitmap class to render your whole UI into an image and than save that where you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is use the new "Remote Display Experience" feature in the latest Insider build of Windows 10 IoT Core (OS Version 10.0.14295.1000).  It's like Remote Desktop for Windows 10 IoT.

Setup instructions are here: https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/RemoteDisplay.htm

Comment: This feature is not supported on raspberry pi's. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/remotedisplay

Comment: The "Windows IoT Remote Client" is not supported on Raspberry Pi.  The client should be run on a full Windows 10 PC.   The "Windows IoT Remote Server" is what runs on the IoT Core device, such as Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, run the [ScreenCapture.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/commandlineutils#take-screenshot) command line tool. This can also be run over SSH or as a local command. Just make sure you have write-access to the local path you give it save the screenshot. e.g:

> start ScreenCapture.exe c:\Data\USERS\DefaultAccount\Pictures\MyCapture.png